# How to compage 2 metaphone results

Tags: php, compare, comparison, metaphone

I'm wondering if there is an efficient way to compare 2 metaphone results in php.

metaphone 1 = OSKRSWRNNTFYFFTFRHNNSSBSTPKTR

metaphone 2 = FYNTTNWSWRNBTRPRTTLRKTFRHKTTRT0BSTPKTRWNRT0SKR

What would a good start or approach ?

Comment: Take a look at the php [`levenshtein()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

Comment: Thanks, at first I wasn't sure it could help me. I gave it a try see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this :

```
<?php

$metaphone1 = "OSKRSWRNNTFYFFTFRHNNSSBSTPKTR";
$metaphone2 = "FYNTTNWSWRNBTRPRTTLRKTFRHKTTRT0BSTPKTRWNRT0SKR";
$metaphone3 = "WERTYTRSDVVQQOSKRSWRNNTFYFFTFRHNNSSBSTPKTR";

echo levenshtein($metaphone1,$metaphone2); // Returns 30
echo levenshtein($metaphone2,$metaphone3); // Returns 36


?>
```